# Voice recognition program works sporadically

Tags: python, voice-recognition, voice, cmusphinx

I am not sure why but it only finds, converts and transcribes all of the mp3 files in the directory occasionally but never 100 percent of the time.  I am not sure why.  I hope I am asking in the right place.    My goal is to find all m4a files and then convert to wav files and then find all wav files and transcribe them.  The program does this some of the time but not all of the time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

    import speech_recognition as sr
    import time
    import subprocess
    import os
    from os import path
    from os import listdir


    # find and convert mp3 files to wav files

    # find all files with an extension, convert to wav files, transcribe to text file then transfer all wav files and mp3 files to finished directory and email transcribed files.

    # find files with mp3 extension

    def list_files1(directory, extension):
        ext = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(extension):
                    ext.append(file)
        print(ext)
        return ext


    # get directory path
    originalDir = os.getcwd()

    # call function to find files with mp3 extension
    mp3files = list_files1(originalDir, "m4a")

    # os.chdir("/Users/williamjohnson/Dropbox/goodscrapers/publimaison2/")

    # convert all mp3 files to wav files
    for x in mp3files:
        print(x)
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        command = "ffmpeg -i " + x + ' ' + timestr + ".wav"
        print(command)
        subprocess.call(command, shell=True)

    # find all converted wav files

    wavfiles = list_files1(originalDir, "wav")

    for y in wavfiles:
        print(y)
        # obtain path to "english.wav" in the same folder as this script
        AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), y)
        # AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "french.aiff")
        # AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "chinese.flac")

        # use the audio file as the audio source
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
            audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file

        # recognize speech using Sphinx
        try:
            print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
            timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
            text_file = open(timestr + ".txt", "a")
            text_file.write(r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
            text_file.close()
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Edit:It was a really dumb mistake that I was making, I was naming all outputted text files with the same name so they were being overwritten I made sure to give them a unique name by going down to the millisecond as the name and then adding a random number to the file name for good measure.

Comment: What happens when it does not work? Do you get an error? Bad transcripts? Something else? Is the problem reproducible, or does it work the next time?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `os.walk()`, it returns the files *without any directory* so you are collecting a list of files but discarding their directory name.

Your wrapper does not seem to be adding any value over `os.walk()`; I would refactor to convert one file at a time anyway.  Tangentially, you also don't need to call `getcwd` if you don't particularly care about the absolute path to the current directory.

```
import os

def get_next_file(directory, extension):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                yield os.path.join(root, file)

for x in get_next_file('.', 'm4a'):
    print(x)
```